# Edit user from another view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I need to edit a user's data from another view. Example, when a user makes a new post, they can change their name, phone number, address, etc. I am using the Devise gem.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit any model/migration from any view. Rails doesn't restrict you on that, though it does try to lead you down the conventional way. In the view you want to edit your `user`, try something like this:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  ...more code here...

<% end %>
```

Just make sure that `@user` is a `user` object.

Comment: I must declare @user = current_user on controller I use ?. Or just take it automatically ?. By using this way automatically uses the controllador to devise registrations?

Comment: Yes, you must have `@user = current_user` in your edit action of the controller you are using. When you submit the form, it will go to the Devise registration controller, unless you override it with your own.